# Can I use 马马虎虎 to describe food, and in what sorts of sentences can I use it?

Tags: word-choice, food, adjectives, word-order

In what kinds of sentences can "马马虎虎" be used? Would I be able to use it to describe how good food tastes, and if so, how would I structure the sentence? Is it usually used by itself as a sentence? I'm never sure if the context is right to use it or not.
I want to describe a food as tasting mediocre.

Comment: Check https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/25522/how-did-%e9%a9%ac%e9%a9%ac%e8%99%8e%e8%99%8e-come-to-mean-so-so also this https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/24249/what-is-the-mandarin-equivalent-of-cantoneses-%e9%ba%bb%e9%ba%bb%e5%9c%b0-so-so

Comment: Similar to the French expression -- Comme ci comme ça  -- Neither good nor bad; so so; tolerable, passable, indifferent.

Comment: Here's a YouTube explanation --https://youtu.be/onlhbVasE94

Comment: Yes, it can be used with anything that is under expectation. It means "so, so" in English.

Answer (score 2):

1. To express a mediocre taste, I think it's better to say

   > 這道菜［很普通/平淡無奇］。
2. `馬虎` is generally used when we wish to comment on someone’s attitude. It may be used when you wish to criticise someone’s *preparation* of the dish as sloppy:

   > 這道菜做得馬馬虎虎。
   > (lit.) This dish is done in a sloppy manner.
3. The sense 'so-so' (`還過得去` in *Cihai*'s definition), as in

   > 這道菜，馬馬虎虎吧。
   > (lit.) This dish, it's so-so.

   , is very colloquial, perhaps regional. It is found in [*Cihai*](http://www.hydcd.com/cd/htm10/ci181554o.htm) but not in [Taiwan dictionaries](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail?title=%E9%A6%AC%E9%A6%AC%E8%99%8E%E8%99%8E&search=%E9%A6%AC%E9%A6%AC%E8%99%8E%E8%99%8E&order=keyword_title).

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can say 这道菜马马虎虎.  Similar use 这台电视马马虎虎。

It can also be used adverbally.  E. g.  他歌唱得马马虎虎。